# Trouble Understanding Fork Logic

Tags: process, fork, system-calls

Can someone help me understand what is happening in this segment of code?  I am having trouble understanding why the output is how it is.  Output is:

> 0 1 2 3 4
>
> 3
>
> 2
>
> 1
>
> 0

```
int main() {
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < 5 && !fork(); i++) {
      fflush(stdout);
      printf("%d ", i);
   }
   wait(NULL);

   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, you've just run into "a programmer who was 'too clever by half.'"  The `fork()` system-call basically creates a *duplicate copy* of whatever process is creating it.  The original process gets a non-zero *(therefore, "true")* return-code from `fork()`.  The child gets zero.  Unfortunately for you, "the original programmer who wrote this code" never endeavored to be clear as to his/her intentions. . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things here:

First, `fork()` return `0` in child process while it returns a non zero pid to the parent process.

Second, short circuit of `&&`.

So in the beginning of the first process (p0), it runs to `i < 5 && !fork()`. Now `i = 0` and another process created (p1). Now for p0, test `!fork()` fails, it ends the for loop and waiting for child to end.  For p1, the test succeeds, and print out `0`, then increment `i` to 1, then it will create process p2 and itself goes out the for loop as p0 did.

Because of short circuiting, when `i` equals 5, no more `fork` will be called.

Comment: could you explain to me how the fflush(stdout) call is working?  It seems to me like the numbers would be double printing because the flush is called on the buffer and then it prints?

Comment: in my understanding, fflush flushes the stream buffer which means if there is something, it will be flushed out. If it is empty, you got nothing. When you print, it first goes to the buffer. But if you call fflush, the results will be shown faster instead of waiting to be flushed when the stream closed or full.